# How to hack an image height standard with jQuery?

Tags: php, function, image

I need a jQuery function to measure the height of an image, and add margin to the IMG element, so it will always result with a regular number that divides by 17 (which is my line-height).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**: I changed the title of the question and replaced PHP with jQuery. Coming to think about it, I need the function to run after the DOM is ready, on all images in a specific DIV. jQuery is more sensible than PHP in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to know how to get each image height and add a margin as needed to get the height to a number evenly divisible by 17.

Here is a quick stab at the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('img').each(function() {
             var height = $(this).height;
             var modulus = height % 17;
             if(modulus != 0) {
                 var marginToAdd = 17 - modulus;
                 $(this).css("margin-bottom", marginToAdd); 
             }
       });
});
```

So what the above does is get each image on the page by it's tag.  If you don't want every image on the page you might want to put all the images in a container so you have a more discriminating selector.  Then it get the remainder from the division of the height by 17.  If the remainder is 0 it does nothing if it is non-zero it figures out the margin that needs to be added to make it evenly divisible by 17 and adds it to the bottom of the image.

Comment: if the image is not loaded, you will need the load method.

Comment: @Alfonso since this starts up in the document.ready event shouldn't the images be loaded by the time this fires?  Genuine question btw my knowledge of the page lifecycle on the client side is a little thin

Comment: @antonlavey in the jQuery doc 'If you want an event to work on your page, you should call it inside the $(document).ready() function. Everything inside it will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded.' I ran into this problem before, the only way I could fix it is like in my response (of course inside doc.ready)

Comment: Ah sweet thanks for the info I wasn't aware it was post DOM but pre-content that the ready event fires.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Looked up the load reference and it looks like if the image is cached it might not fire.  What would work all the time however is putting this in a $(window).load()

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).children("img").attr("height")
```

There is a very similar question here: [Using jQuery each to grab image height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273862/using-jquery-each-to-grab-image-height)

Comment: wrong because the height will be returned only when the attribute is set on the html tag plus the browser won't know the size until the image is loaded, that could be before or after the document ready event

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has some problems with document ready and image load on this issue.

if you want to check the image sizes you need to know if the image has been loaded or not because you can have the dom ready without the images loaded or the image will not trigger the onload event

so:

```
var image = $('#image');
if(image.get(0).complete){
    do_what_you_need();
} else {
    image.load(function(e){
        do_what_you_need();             
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GD library: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 0):

You can get image height with jquery simply by doing

```
 $('#my_img_id').height();
```

For DOM ready, just check http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Edit:
Is that what you were looking for?

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#myDiv img').each(function(){
        alert($(this).height()); 
    });
});

</script>
<div id="myDiv">
    <img src="asd.png">
    <img src="gg.png">
</div>
```